# Read json file and update existing excel using python pandas

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas

excel_file name = `exl.xlsx`

**Excel data:**

```
name  surname   email  
a     sname     abc.com  
b     sname2    efg.com
```

json file name = `input.json`

**json data**

```
{
 "a":
    {
     "friend1":4444444444,
     "friend2":5555555555,
     "friend3":1111111111
    },
 "b":
    {
     "friend3":6565656565,
     "friend2":9999999999,
     "friend5":9999988888
    }
}  


import json  
import panda as pd  

json_data = json.load(open(input.json))  
data = pd.read_json(json_data)  

excel_file = pd.read_excel(exl.xlsx, na_filter=False, header=0)
```

I want to update excel file in such a way that you match the name from json to excel and add a new column in excel with name "listOfFriends" and for that matched name you update the column

```
name  surname   email    listOfFriends  
a     sname     abc.com  friend1, friend2, friend3  
b     sname2    efg.com  friend3, friend2, friend5
```

Answer (score 1):

Say you start with

```
j = """
{
 "a":
    {
     "friend1":4444444444,
     "friend2":5555555555,
     "friend3":1111111111
    },
 "b":
    {
     "friend3":6565656565,
     "friend2":9999999999,
     "friend5":9999988888
    }
}
"""
```

Then

```
pd.Series({k: list(v) for k, v in json.loads(j).items()}).to_frame().rename(columns={0: 'listOfFriends'})
```

gives

```
    listOfFriends
a   [friend1, friend2, friend3]
b   [friend3, friend2, friend5]
```

If you assign this to `friends`, you just need to

```
pd.merge(excel_file, friends, left_on='name', right_index=True)
```

and write the results back to the Excel file.

Comment: It throws this error when I assign it to friends and do pd.merge

ValueError: can not merge DataFrame with instance of type <class 'collections.OrderedDict'>

Comment: Are you using `OrderedDict` anywhere in your code? There isn't any in mine, so I assume you're doing something differently. On what exactly are you doing the merge, and can you check the types of both operands?

Comment: I am just assigning 
friends = pd.Series({k: list(v) for k, v in json.loads(j).items()}).to_frame().rename(columns={0: 'listOfFriends'})

and then use the pd.merge and for json data I am reading from the file like :
json_data = json.load(open(input.json))  
data = pd.read_json(json_data)  
j=data.to_json()